# setInterval with setState in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a timer using `setInterval()` in a React component and I'm unsure what the best practices are in order to start and stop this interval in respect to using `state`. I'm running into some asynchronous issues with that.

Let's say I have a set of links in my React component that render and execute the callback fine:

```
let links = [10, 50, 100, 500, 1000].map((num) => {
  return(
    <Link key={num} onClick={(e) => this.switchNums(num)} to={`/somePath/${num}`}>{num}</Link>
  )
})
```

Here's the `switchNums()` function, where i want it to reset an existing timer:

```
switchNums(num){
  this.stopTimer()
  this.reset(num)
}
```

Here's `startTimer()`, `stopTimer()` and `reset()`:

```
startTimer(){
  if(!this.state.timerId){      
    let timerId = setInterval(()=>{
      let timer = this.state.timer + 1
      this.setState({
        timer: timer,
        timerId: timerId
      })
    }, 1000)
  }
}

stopTimer(){
  clearInterval(this.state.timerId)     
  this.setState({timerId:null})
}

reset(size){
  this.setState({
    gameOver: false,
    counter: 0,
    correct: 0,
    numbers: this.getRandomNumbers(size),
    timer: 0
  }, this.startTimer())
}
```

One of the bugs is clicking on the links rapidly will cause multiple intervals to fire despite the `if` condition in `startTimer()`. I'm guessing this has to do with the asynchronous nature of `setState()`. Another bug (and I think related) is that when i click slowly, it only starts the interval every other time.

Can anyone shed some light on this? Or what they've done to circumvent asynchronous issues with `setState` being used in conjunction with `setInterval`(any way set state can return a promise?), Or which lifecycle methods would be best for this type of situation?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think the biggest flaw here is that you're using `state` to store your interval. While technically possible, I see no reason why you would actually want to do that.

Instead, just use a local variable to your component:

```
startTimer(){
  if(!this.timerId){     
    this.timerId = setInterval(()=>{
      //your function
    }, 1000);
  }
}

stopTimer(){
  clearInterval(this.timerId);
}
```

So I don't think you need to use the `state` at all here for your timer. You have some other general questions in your post though that are related to `state`, and I'll try to answer those below. Just bear in mind that they are irrelevant in solving your particular issue.

---

**What have they've done to circumvent asynchronous issues with `setState()`?**

You can use a callback to execute code *after* the `state` has been set. There's a [section of the official docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate) about this; here's what it says:

> The second parameter is an optional callback function that will be executed once setState is completed and the component is re-rendered.

```
setState(nextState, callback);
```

---

**Which lifecycle methods would be best for this type of situation?**

The same section of the doc as above continues:

> Generally we recommend using componentDidUpdate() for such logic instead.

If you have multiple `setState` in your function, and you want to execute specific code after a specific event, I think you're fine using the callback. For more general purposes use the life-cycle method above.

Comment: my god, you can just store things in the component itself... thank you! gonna try it

Comment: Thank you so much! this worked perfectly. So this might be another SO question itself, but what other things are properties of the component rather than in it's state or props? (besides methods)

Comment: None by default. Remember that `state` and `props` are actually properties of the `this` object (you type them as `this.state` and `this.props`) -- so is your `this.timer` variable.

Comment: right, but i guess the convention to know that interval or timeout ID's should be stored as direct properties and not in state, is that strictly because of the async nature of intervals/timeouts? Or are there other common things that are stored as direct properties, ie not in state or props of the component(`this`)

Comment: Both `state` and `props` should only contain data that if changed should trigger a re-render of your component. In other words, if it's not data that directly (or at least in-directly) affects the render-output of your component, then it shouldn't be part of the `state` or `props`.

Comment: @chris thank you for adding the setState(nextState, callback); in your answer. This saved me a lot of time

Answer (score 2):

Using React Hooks `useState` and `useEffect` you can do the following:

```js
const [timer, setTimer] = useState(1);

useEffect(() => {
  const timerId = setInterval(() => setTimer(timer + 1), 1000);

  return () => clearInterval(timerId);
});
```