# React Components and setInterval ID

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setinterval

I'm attempting to write a Notification React component that pops up and then disappears after 5 seconds. There can be many Notifications that stack on each other, so I keep a list of them and display them using `map()`. However, I noticed that if I sequentially add Notifications and declare the setInterval ID inside each of them, as they unmount, the ID migrates from one component to the next. For example, let's say that Notification ID 111 gets setInterval ID 1, and then Notification ID 222 is created and gets setInterval ID 2. Once Notification 111 disappears, all of a sudden Notification 222's setInterval ID is now 1! Here is the relevant code:

```
class Notification extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onClose = this.onClose.bind(this);
    this.countdownTimer = null;
    this.secondsLeft = null;
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    if(this.secondsLeft === null) {
      this.secondsLeft = 5;
      this.countdownTimer = setInterval(() => {
        this.secondsLeft = this.secondsLeft - 1;
        if (this.secondsLeft <= 0) {
          this.onClose();
        };
      }, 1000);
    };
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.countdownTimer);
  }

  onClose() {
    this.props.removeNotification(this.props.notification.id);
  }

// render() and other irrelevant code removed
}
```

Why is the value `this.countdownTimer` being transferred to another component once the component is removed? Could it be that the list of Notifications points to them by position in the list rather than the props given?

EDIT: Here are the relevant logs to prove it:

```
// Notification ID: 5a8 , timer ID: 15 , secondsLeft: 5
// Notification ID: 15a , timer ID: 16 , secondsLeft: 5
// Notification ID: 5a8 , timer ID: 15 , secondsLeft: 4
// Notification ID: 15a , timer ID: 16 , secondsLeft: 4
// Notification ID: 5a8 , timer ID: 15 , secondsLeft: 3
// Notification ID: 15a , timer ID: 16 , secondsLeft: 3
// Notification ID: 5a8 , timer ID: 15 , secondsLeft: 2
// Notification ID: 15a , timer ID: 16 , secondsLeft: 2
// Notification ID: 5a8 , timer ID: 15 , secondsLeft: 1
// Notification ID: 15a , timer ID: 15 , secondsLeft: 0
```

Comment: Never modify state directly. Try and fix `this.secondsLeft = this.secondsLeft - 1` with a `this.setState()`.

Comment: True, use state of component to preserve values per component. Clear the state when component unmounts.

Comment: Make sure each `<Notification />` has a unique `key` as well.

Comment: I already had secondsLeft as a state variable, but changed it as per this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40510885/2451856

Comment: I think the comment about `key` is the right thing to look into. React uses the `key` prop as a way to know when you're inserting/removing components from a list, and delete the appropriate component. It looks like your notifications already have an ID, so you have a natural value to provide as a `key`.

Answer (score 0):

I realized my mistake. I was setting the `key` prop in the Notification component itself. I should have been setting the `key` inside of my `map()` when initializing the component. For example:

```
class NotificationsList extends Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <div className="NotificationsList">
          { this.props.notifications.map(notification => (
            <Notification
              notification={notification}
              key={notification.id}
            />
          ))}
        </div>
      );
    }
}
```

Originally I had instead been doing this (which was wrong):

```
class Notification extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <AnimatedAlert
        key={this.props.notification.id}
      </AnimatedAlert>
    );
  }
}
```